# Why @RequestParam annotation bind the value from request body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void test(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
    modelMap.put("result",name);
}
```

When I call this request from Postman and pass the `Name` parameter in the request body and in the URL, the result is like this :

[image: The result is from body]

But if I remove the parameter from request body, the request is like this :

[image: The result is from head]

Why does `@RequestParam` annotation bind the value from the request body first? and if it doesn't exist in the body, it bind the value from URL parameters

Answer (score 2):

Because it's how [ServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) works. Behind the scene @RequestParam is using [ServletRequest#getParameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-). If you take a look at the java doc it clearly state that query parameter or form post data are used.

> For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

If there is a multiple value for instance same key in query and post data then it returns the first value in the array returned by [getParameterValues](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-).

Furthermore you are using `multipart/form-data` content type so spring handle it with `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest` where parameters found in the body are returned first:

```
@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
    String[] parameterValues = super.getParameterValues(name);
    String[] mpValues = getMultipartParameters().get(name);
    if (mpValues == null) {
        return parameterValues;
    }
    if (parameterValues == null || getQueryString() == null) {
        return mpValues;
    }
    else {
        String[] result = new String[mpValues.length + parameterValues.length];
        System.arraycopy(mpValues, 0, result, 0, mpValues.length);
        System.arraycopy(parameterValues, 0, result, mpValues.length, parameterValues.length);
        return result;
    }
}
```